# Open source examples of well written SCM web interface in Perl

Tags: perl, version-control, web-applications, open-source

Can anyone point me to some good Open Source web interface for VCS (version control system) written in Perl?

Something well written, so I can examine the code and steal the best parts (or organization) for gitweb. Preferably something without tons of external dependences not available in (extended) Perl core.

Comment: Maybe you can list the ones you have considered and rejected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't looked at the source code of [SVN::Web](http://search.cpan.org/dist/SVN-Web/), so I can't tell you if it's well written, but I sure like to use it. [Here](http://deps.cpantesters.org/?module=SVN%3A%3AWeb&perl=any+version&os=any+OS) is a list of the dependencies, and you can [see it in action](http://perlcabal.org/svn/pugs/revision/?rev=27740).

Answer (score 1):

Have you has a look at [CvsMonitor](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cvsmonitor/)?  Its a little old but its a perl web interface into CVS.

Comment: Do you know any demo site where I can see CvsMonitor in action (preferably with CvsMonitor code to browse)? Sourceforge uses ViewVC, and homepage link for CvsMonitor on SF is broken.

Comment: Not really, we used it internally at my previous job. If you google for cvsmonitor.pl you can find some working examples. It looks like the Drupal project uses it http://drupal.kollm.org/cvsmonitor/cvsmonitor.pl . I also don't think the project has had much activity since 2004, hence the abandoned look of the Sourceforge page, tho i think it has some nice ideas. I especially like the Karma feature it has which gives you a score based on your commits and other behaviors